# Advice on FParsec for handling whitespace

Tags: f#, fparsec

I have the following subexpression to parse 'quotes' which have the following format

```
"5.75 @ 5.95"
```

I therefore have this parsec expression to parse it

```
let pquote x = (sepBy (pfloat) ((spaces .>> (pchar '/' <|>  pchar '@' )>>. spaces))) x
```

It works fine.. except when there is a trailing space in my input, as the separator expression starts to consume content.So I wrapped it around an attempt, which works and seems, from what I understand,  more or less what this was meant to be.

```
let pquote x = (sepBy (pfloat) (attempt (spaces .>> (pchar '/' <|>  pchar '@' )>>. spaces))) x
```

As I dont know fparsec so well, I wonder if there are any better way to write this. it seems a bit heavy (while still being very manageable of course)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let s1 = "5.75         @             5.95              "
let s2 = "5.75/5.95   "
let pquote: Parser<_> =
    pfloat
    .>> spaces .>> skipAnyOf ['@'; '/'] .>> spaces
    .>>. pfloat
    .>> spaces
```

Notes:

1. <strike>I've made `spaces` optional everywhere</strike> `spaces` skips any sequence of *zero* or more whitespaces, so there's no need to use `opt` - thanks @Daniel;
2. `type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, UserState>` - I define it this way in order to avoid "value restriction" error; you may remove it;
3. <s>Also, don't forget the following if your program may run on a system with default language settings having decimal comma: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture <- Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo "en-US"`</s> this won't work, thanks @Stephan
4. I would not use `sepBy` unless I have a value list of unknown size.
5. If you don't really need the value returned (e.g. `'@'` characters), it is recommended to use `skip*` functions instead `p*` for performance considerations.

*UPD* added slash as separator

Comment: your project is crazy. you are crazy. good to see some parsec used here, testimony of quality I guess.

Comment: [`spaces`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.spaces) parses zero or more whitespaces--no need to use `opt`.

Comment: @bytebuster The `pfloat` parser only accepts decimal points and then parses the number with the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, so I don't think you need to set the `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably do something like this, which returns `float * float`:

```
let ws = spaces
let quantity = pfloat .>> ws
let price = pfloat .>> ws
let quoteSep = pstring "@" .>> ws
let quote = quantity .>> quoteSep .>>. price //`.>> eof` (if final parser)
```

It's typical for each parser to consume trailing whitespace. Just make sure your top-level parser includes `eof`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you could have more than two `float` in the input and '/' and '@' are delimiters:

```
let ws = spaces
let str_ws s = pstring s .>> ws
let float_ws = pfloat .>> ws
let pquote = sepBy float_ws (str_ws "/" <|> str_ws "@")
```

Talking about handling whitespaces, [this section](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#handling-whitespace) in FParsec tutorial is really helpful.